# How to get back deleted colab-jupyter.log file in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I have deleted the `colab-jupyter.log` file from `var/log/` folder in google colab. Problem is now even if I manually created a `colab-jupyter.log` file, nothing is written over there.

I deleted it to clear the content of it to better understand the log file messages. What is the possible solution now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem. I deleted it. And then created a new file `colabjupyter.log`. It was not writing any logs. So all I needed to do was to factory reset the runtime. And that did the trick. Nothing to panic about. Phew.